# tmux homebrew C-B prefix not working on macosx

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I am new to tmux. I use **screen** for remote session. After reading a few tutorials online I am very surprise. So I want to give it a try as tmux is easier to use and more customizable for me as a developer.

I am on macosx sierra and install tmux via homebrew but after creating a session I used C-B prefix command for example C-B % to split but it did not work.

Can anyone tell me how to debug this or is there any setting for this to work?

ps: I also try a few combination cmd+b+% ,...

Comment: 1.) Are you sure you're using the default prefix (`^C-b`)? You should be able to sniff out the current prefix by running the following in your terminal: `tmux list-keys | grep send-prefix`. 2.) You've used the character "B" (as opposed to "b") throughout your post. Are you actually pressing `control shift+b`? If so, that's likely your problem.

Comment: I used no shift. C-B is what I saw in  written in blogs.

Comment: after grepping the list-keys i got this:  bind-key    -T prefix C-b              send-prefix  is there anything wrong?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think you may want to remove that `-T` flag from your .tmux.conf. (Also, since it appears to be relevant, you should probably add the contents of your .tmux.conf file to the question body.)

Comment: I installed it from homebrew there is no .tmux.conf file in my home dir and brew.

Comment: For the sake of argument, try adding [this](https://gist.github.com/ethagnawl/bdf502e4cdc54a32e8ded917dafb3501) to ~/.tmux.conf and seeing if `^C-a` works.